# gcloud app versions delete and gcloud app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm very confused about deployment on app engine for my java application. After a couple of try by using gcloud app deploy --stop-previous-version and receive an error :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: IN_USE_ADDRESSES (quota: 8, used: 8 + needed: 2).
```

I decided to disable my project in the settings. But when I run :

gcloud app instances list

I'm still getting this output :

```
<code>
SERVICE  VERSION          ID                                VM_STATUS  VM_LIVENESS  DEBUG_MODE
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-0v2b  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-8k8f  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-8p5v  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-ggcs  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-rjh0  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-t42r  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
default  20210916t134322  aef-default-20210916t134322-z9vw  RUNNING    TIMEOUT
</code>
```

If I try to delete an instance from the cli :
gcloud app versions delete 20210916t134322

I got the following exception

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.delete) The default service (module) may not be deleted, and must comprise at least one version.
```

And I'm still not able to deploy anymore my project !

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not allow you to delete `version: 20210916t134322` is because you need to have at least one version for the `default` service. You may follow this steps:

1. Create a new version
2. [Migrate](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/migrate) default service traffic to the new version
3. Delete the old version

As for the quota error, you may try to specify [maximum instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling) and deploy this in `app.yaml` to avoid such error:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 7
```

Comment: Hi first of all, thanks for your response. I updated my app.yaml file and deleted the instance of my project. I created a new one but now when I run gcloud config set project sneakerapp
Updated property [core/project].
WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [sneakerapp] or it does not exist. Or when I run gcloud app instances list
ERROR: (gcloud.app.instances.list) User [xxxxxx@gmail.com] does not have permission to access apps instance [sneakerapp] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Comment: I fix this problem by recreating an app to google app engine within flexible and java env but now I'm still getting an 502 Server Error,,,,

Comment: It appears that you have a new problem. Stack Overflow guideline is to focus on one problem per question. Please post a new question so other people can take a look into it.